# How to insert multiple rows with one insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert new rows into my DB. I have 155 rows that I need to insert. What is happening is that I am adding new users based on an existing account table. I have a query that lists the new users that I need to add to the users table, but I don't want to have to type out the insert 155 times. Is there an easier way of doing this? I've seen where you can have multiple sets of 'Values' in the insert, but I'm not sure how I would implement this. For example:

```
insert into tblUsers (State,City,Code)
Values ('IN','Indy',(select UserCode from tblAccounts where UserCode in(Select UserCode from tblAccounts where State = 'IN')))
```

I know that my sub-query will return 155 values and so won't actually work here, is there a way to modify this so that it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers (State,City,Code)
SELECT 'IN','Indy', UserCode
FROM tblAccounts
WHERE UserCode IN
    (SELECT UserCode
     FROM tblAccounts
     WHERE State = 'IN')
```

or better simplified (a subquery is not needed):

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers (State,City,Code)
SELECT 'IN','Indy', UserCode
FROM tblAccounts
WHERE State = 'IN'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tblUsers (State,City,Code)
   Select 'IN','Indy',  UserCode 
   from tblAccounts 
   where UserCode in (Select UserCode 
                     from tblAccounts 
                     where State = 'IN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers (State,City,Code)
SELECT 'IN','Indy', UserCode 
FROM tblAccounts 
WHERE UserCode IN (SELECT UserCode FROM tblAccounts WHERE State = 'IN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
INSERT INTO tblUsers (State,City,Code)
SELECT 'IN','Indy', UserCode
FROM tblAccounts
WHERE State = 'IN'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only insert from another table, like this:

```
insert into tblUsers (State,City,Code)
SELECT * FROM table1
```